# What is an efficient way to split an array into a training and testing set in Julia?

Tags: arrays, optimization, machine-learning, julia

So I am running a machine learning algorithm in Julia with limited spare memory on my machine. Anyway, I have noticed a rather large bottleneck in the code I am using from the repository. It seems that splitting the array (randomly) takes even longer than reading the file from disk which seems to highlight code's inefficiencies. As I said before, any tricks to speed up this function would be greatly appreciated. The original function can be found [here](https://github.com/aaw/IncrementalSVD.jl/blob/master/src/util.jl). Since it's a short function, I'll post it below as well.

```
# Split a list of ratings into a training and test set, with at most
# target_percentage * length(ratings) in the test set. The property we want to
# preserve is: any user in some rating in the original set of ratings is also
# in the training set and any item in some rating in the original set of ratings
# is also in the training set. We preserve this property by iterating through
# the ratings in random order, only adding an item to the test set only if we
# haven't already hit target_percentage and we've already seen both the user
# and the item in some other ratings.
function split_ratings(ratings::Array{Rating,1},
                       target_percentage=0.10)
    seen_users = Set()
    seen_items = Set()
    training_set = (Rating)[]
    test_set = (Rating)[]
    shuffled = shuffle(ratings)
    for rating in shuffled
        if in(rating.user, seen_users) && in(rating.item, seen_items) && length(test_set) < target_percentage * length(shuffled)
            push!(test_set, rating)
        else
            push!(training_set, rating)
        end
        push!(seen_users, rating.user)
        push!(seen_items, rating.item)
    end
    return training_set, test_set
end
```

As previously stated, anyway I can push the data would be greatly appreciated. I also will note that I do not really need to retain the ability to remove duplicates, but it would be a nice feature. Also if this is already implemented in a Julia library I would be grateful to know about it. Bonus points for any solutions that leverage that parallelism abilities of Julia!

Comment: Check out https://github.com/JuliaML/MLDataUtils.jl

Comment: Doesn't the automatic routing of singleton ratings (ones that are unique for an item or a user) to the training set [possibly] generate a  bias for the learning algorithm?

Comment: I didn't implement the original algorithm, anyway I ignored that part in the code I ended up using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the most efficient code I could come up with in terms of memory.

```
function splitratings(ratings::Array{Rating,1}, target_percentage=0.10)
  N = length(ratings) 
  splitindex = round(Integer, target_percentage * N)
  shuffle!(ratings) #This shuffles in place which avoids the allocation of another array!
  return sub(ratings, splitindex+1:N), sub(ratings, 1:splitindex) #This makes subarrays instead of copying the original array!
end
```

However, Julia's incredibly slow file IO is now the bottleneck. This algorithm takes about 20 seconds to run on an array of 170 million elements so I say it''s rather performant.

Comment: This duplicates the element at the `splitindex` across both the testing and training sets; use `splitindex+1:N`.  Also note that `iround` is deprecated in version 0.4.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! Duplicating the split index isn't a terrible issue, but I'll fix it really fast in my post.